# Can't select an option using Selenium + Python

Tags: python, selenium, select

I can click on a field, so drop down appears, but then I am stuck 
It has:

```
<select class="choices select optional choices__input is-hidden chzn-select foursix chzn-done" name="pack[company_billing_plan_id]" id="pack_company_billing_plan_id" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true" data-choice="active">
<option value = "A" selected = ""> NAME </option>
```

where A and NAME tend to change depends on the option you choose, so they are different each time.
Any ideas on how to make the thing real and to do that?

PS. My part of the code:

```
self.group.choice = self.session.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/section[2]/div[2]/div/'
                                                                     'form/fieldset[1]/dl[2]/dd/div/div[1]')
self.group.choice.click()
```

Comment: Why is an option (NAME) out of select?

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you are using xpath for the object identication and its getting changed as whatever is being selected there.

Try to select the nth-child of the parent object which are having non dynamic properties

by_css = [select*="choices select optional choices"] > a:nth-child(no)

no = whatever element u want to reach(1,2,3,)